# Codenameone IOS In-app purchase with IPv6

Tags: in-app-purchase, codenameone, ipv6

I created an app with in-app purchase function by Codenameone, after submit the IOS build to Apple, it is rejected due to following reason

"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
Specifically, we are unable to complete the In-App-Purchase process in your app."

From apple's screenshot, itemPurchaseError callback is triggered, is Codenameone in-app purchase function support IPv6 or not? Thank you

Below is the code used to trigger In-app purchase

> Button in_app_purchase_btn = new Button("BuyProfessional");            >in_app_purchase_btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> Purchase.getInAppPurchase().purchase(SKU_Prof));

Comment: Yes. It should work with IPv6.  What error code/message was returned by the purchase error? Have you tested it on an iOS device yourself?  My best advice is to try really hard to reproduce the error yourself.  Then you'll be in a much better position to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The IPv6 is a red herring in the error messages from Apple. It's always there to explain the environment where the failure happens. This doesn't mean they observed the app working on an IPv4 network then crashing on an IPv6 network, it just describes their environment where they saw the crash.

They usually have additional notes describing the crash they observed and you can write to the tester and ask for details if you can't see any.

Since Apples entire testing facility is IPv6 and apps pass QA Codename One obviously works on IPv6 networks without a problem.

Comment: Apple just rejected my cn1 app for bad request 400 while doing some http, it also said it was on an ipv6 network, do you think this is also a red herring? Ie a server issue or could it still be app related?

Comment: That's unrelated to ipv6. You can't use HTTP on iOS unless you have a good reason. You must use HTTPS see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html 400 is a server error so you can look through the server logs and see what went wrong